# Pass multiple arguments to javascript function from JSP scriptlet out.println

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

`out.println("<button type='button' class='button' onClick='addProgressGoal(" + g.getGoalProgress() + g.getGoalID() + g.getTargetValue() + ")'>Add Progress</button>");`

How can I pass three seperate values in the addProgressGoal as just using + is obviously just sending across one value of g.getGoalProgress(), g.getGoalID() and g.getTargetValue() added together.

Here is my function:

```
        function addProgressGoal(progress, id, target) {
```

For some reason I just cannot seem to send all three across in valid code

Comment: Show the function `addProgressGoal()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

```
out.println("<button type='button' class='button' onClick='addProgressGoal(" + g.getGoalProgress() +", "+ g.getGoalID() +", "+ g.getTargetValue() + ")'>Add Progress</button>");
```

Commas between parameters ?

Comment: Yeah, great thanks a lot. I guess I just exhausted many options and didn't even think of this! Thanks.